# Displaying Flask-WTF error shows extra characters

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I want to display an error from a field in my Flask-WTF form with JavaScript.  Printing out `form.errors['password']` gives `['This field is required']`, but I don't want `['` `']` in the output.  How do I display the error in the right format?

Comment: @Craicerjack Ah.. Pycharm have 2.8. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I don't think that `extract` is a jinja bultin filter. If it's a custom filter did you install the library that provides that filter?

Comment: Yeah so there is no built in `extract` filter. List of built in filters - http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters. Your line of code looks like its from the `ansible` docs - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers

Comment: @Craicerjack Oh, I was trying it from this site. I didn't know that are exists more jinja filters than original. Thank you

Comment: @HonzaSedloň there are built in ones like the list above and then there are custom ones that you can create. Ansible obviously created the filter youre trying to use. So its no in flask or jinja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each field can have multiple errors, so they are always contained in a list, even if there is only one error.  There is nothing special about Jinja or Flask-WTF here, you just need to pay attention to the data you're working with.

```
{{ form.password.errors[0] }}
{{ form.errors['password'][0] }}
```